# condition statetment in while, not works

Tags: php, laravel, loops, while-loop

I have problem with using while in laravel, i think this source code is already correct, but when run it, it does not work.

For my problem, i have env('NILAI_K') = 3, $res is storing array from a function result.

When $res count equal to 0, it keep passing the if statement and update $checker to true.

```
$checker=false;
while(!$checker)
{
    $res = $this->euclidianDistanceValidation2($compare->tweet_stemmed,1,40,$startId,$max);
    if(count($res)==env("NILAI_K"))
    {
        echo count($res)."<br/>";
        $checker=true;
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this source?. I Attach some pic to describe the problem
[Problem Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SiQ4.png)

**Updated :**
I try print env value each ite, ex:

```
It1 env('NILAI_K')." ENV".
.
.
.
Itn env('NILAI_K')." ENV".
```

But some it give me this result

```
It1 "3 ENV"
It2 "3 ENV"
It3 "3 ENV"
.
.
Itn " ENV"
```

Comment: `var_dump(count($res), env("NILAI_K"));` before `if`

Comment: @u_mulder i already do it, and some of env is null, why it happen?. Even in my function, "while" is not working

Comment: Have you set checker to false before the while?

Comment: What do you mean by "some of env is null"? Try to debug, put a breakpoint on the `if` and check both values on each iteration.

Comment: try to print gettype($res) before if statement and check if the last iteration makes your if condition true